# Change a buch of dates, regex and python

Tags: python, regex, time, python-2.7

I have a bunch of dates in the following format

```
16th February 2011
4th April 2009
31st December 2007
```

And i want to change them to this format

```
20110216
20090404
20071231
```

I want to do this in python, I've tried `regex` and `time`, but can't get my head round it.

Comment: Normally, I recommend using `time.strptime`, but those ordinals are going to cause problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may wish to consider [parsedatetime](https://github.com/bear/parsedatetime) for fuzzy date matching.

If your dates are fairly invariant from that format of NN(ordinal) Month Year, this works:

```
dates="""\
16th February 2011
4th April 2009
31st December 2007"""

import re
import time

for date in dates.splitlines():
    p=re.findall(r'(\d+)\w\w (\w+) (\d\d\d\d)',date)
    d=time.strptime(' '.join(p[0]),'%d %B %Y')
    iso=time.strftime('%Y%m%d',d)
    print "{0:>20} =>{1:>30} =>{2:>15}".format(date,p,iso)
```

prints:

```
  16th February 2011 =>  [('16', 'February', '2011')] =>       20110216
      4th April 2009 =>      [('4', 'April', '2009')] =>       20090404
  31st December 2007 =>  [('31', 'December', '2007')] =>       20071231
```

Answer (score 0):

without imports, for learning purposes.

months is a dictionary of months.

```
months = {"January":"01","February":"02",...}    
# make sure all entries are strings, not integers

for entry in entries:
    # split by spaces.  this is multiple assignment.  
    # the first split gets assigned to date, the second, to month, the third, to year.
    day, month, year = entry.split() 

    # parse the date.  the th/rd/nd part is always 2 characters.  
    date = day[:-2]

    if len(date) == 1:
        # make sure the date is two characters long
        date = "0" + date 

    # concatenate
    print year + months[month] + date
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it in two steps:

1. Using regex `(\d+)([a-z]{2})\s+([A-Za-z]+)\s+(\d{4})` replace second group with empty string
2. Use `time.strptime(string[, format])` to convert date to format you need

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to get the info, then strptime to turn it into a date.

```
import datetime
import re
date_re = re.compile("^([0-9]+)[a-z]* (.+)$")
example = "16th February 2011"
m = date_re.match(example)
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime("%s %s" % (m.group(1), m.group(2)), "%d %B %Y")
print dt.strftime("%Y%m%d")
```